# Catch Timeout expired from ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, timeout

I have a ASP site (with VBScript) that connects to a SQL 2005 database.

I would like to be able to catch the timeout expired error, through the err object, but I cannot manage to find any documentation that tells me the err.number for timeout expired.

Can you help me with this one?

Comment: Can you look at Err.Description and check whether it contains "Timeout expired"?

Comment: I could...but what if the user uses a different language? I cannot very in all possible languages....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error number is -2147217871.
The value is documented on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190606